# Static block store_url is appending a session id placeholder in url

Tags: url, static-block

Using a url in static block like this `{{store url=door-machinery.html}}` and getting this on the end `?<!--%20fpc%20session_id_placeholder%20-->`. Any idea what's causing this and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EE?  This looks like a PageCache artifact.  When you are hole-punching through FPC, Magento creates snippets like that.  Then Magento parses the cached responses for those "placeholders" and replaces them with the proper dynamic content.

Comment: Yes, I do have an EE2 site sitting next to the Magento site. Any way to remove that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "EE2 site sitting next to the Magento site"

Comment: site root are the ee2 site files and in another directory /store is the magento site. They are not integrated...in other words magento is inside the root of the ee in a directory called /store. Does that clarify?